# Position a div below another div x pixels from the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I need to show an image at the bottom of a web page after rows of data (dynamic) have been displayed.

See diagram

[image: Diagram]

I have the following html code;

```
<div id="wrapper">
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" SCROLL="no" >
<div class="data_area">
// rows of data. could be between 1 and 10 rows.
</div>

<div class="logoImage">
    <div class="wrapperImage">
    <img src="../../images/imagee.png" width="289"     height="143" />
    <div class="TodaysDate"><?php echo $ToDayDate;?></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1080px;
    position: relative;
}

.data_area {
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

.logoImage {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapperImage {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I need the image div to stay at the bottom of the page even if there is only one row of data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `absolute` positioning? You could do something like this:

```
.logoImage {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Is that the desired effect you want?

Or if you want it fixed when the user scrolls and keep it `25px` from the bottom:

```
.logoImage {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to see your div to be top of your screen. you need to position that div as fixed. and it's parent div must need to stay at relative position.

```
.logoImage {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Your question is not really clear. But maybe this can fix your issue.